# How to manage exceptions when using gtkada

Tags: exception, gtk, ada, gnat

When I'm using gtkada and my GUI is running, no exception is managed and the program always crashes. The message is

*This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.*

Please contact the application's support team for more information.

A test code is as follows:

```
    with GLib;          use GLib;
    with Gtk.Label;     use Gtk.Label;
    with Gtk.Window;    use Gtk.Window;
    with Gtk.Frame;     use Gtk.Frame;
    with Gtk.Button;    use Gtk.Button;
    with Gtk.Widget;    use Gtk.Widget;

    with Gtk.Handlers;
    with Gtk.Main;


    procedure gui_test_4 is
       Window          : Gtk_Window;
       Label           : Gtk_Label;
       Frame           : Gtk_Frame;
       Button_S        : Gtk_Button;
       General_Error   : exception;

       package Handlers is new Gtk.Handlers.Callback (Gtk_Widget_Record);
       package Return_Handlers is
          new Gtk.Handlers.Return_Callback (Gtk_Widget_Record, Boolean);

       function Delete_Event (Widget : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class)
          return Boolean is
       begin
          return False;
       end Delete_Event;

       procedure Destroy (Widget : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is
       begin
          Gtk.Main.Main_Quit;
       end Destroy;

       procedure Clicked (Widget : access Gtk_Widget_Record'Class) is
       begin

          raise General_Error;
        exception
            when General_Error =>
              null;

       end Clicked;


    begin
       Gtk.Main.Init;
       Gtk.Window.Gtk_New (Window);
       Set_Default_Size (Window, 200, 200);
       Gtk.Window.Set_Title (Window, "GUI_Test_4");
       Gtk_New (Frame);
       Add (Window, Frame);
       Gtk_New (Button_S, "Try");
       Add (Frame, Button_S);

       Return_Handlers.Connect
       (  Window,
          "delete_event",
          Return_Handlers.To_Marshaller (Delete_Event'Access)
       );
       Handlers.Connect
       (  Window,
          "destroy",
          Handlers.To_Marshaller (Destroy'Access)
       );
       Handlers.Connect
       (  Button_S,
          "clicked",
          Handlers.To_Marshaller (Clicked'Access)
       );

       Show_All (Window);
       Show (Window);

       Gtk.Main.Main;

    end gui_test_4;
```

When the button is pressed, an exception is raised, but it should be managed in the same procedure, but instead of that, the complete program crashes.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Guessing that you are on windows, try to build the same project without '-mwindows' switch (or run `gui_test_4.exe > log.txt` from console) and post if your problem is gone :)

Comment: Actually I'm not using the switch, and it doesn't work. It still crashes. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hmm, strange (i thought you're somehow trying to access non-existent console, hence the crash); nevertheless, i can compile and run `gui_test_4` without any glitch (on both, windows/linux). Just for reference, on windows i'm building it as follows: `gnatmake -g -E gui_test_4.adb -Ic:\bin\gtkada\include\gtkada -largs -LC:/bin/gtkada/lib/gtkada -lgtkada -LC:/bin/gtkada/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0`

Comment: GNAT/GtkAda versions are `2012-i686-pc-mingw32` and `2.24.2-nt` respectively, both from AdaCore.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for your answer.I have the theory now that it is my pc, I have to try in another pc and if it works, I should fix first my windows then. I tried the building command and still it crashed. So I'll try in other pc. Thanks

Comment: It worked in another pc, it seems that the problem is with mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for the debugger to me.

In the comments it was mentioned that others are able to successfully run and build this same code. That could mean that your version of GTKAda has issues. It could instead mean that there's a real bug in there, but how/if it expresses depends on what garbage values happened to be loaded into what memory areas when the program starts up.

You might start off by making sure you have the latest version of GTKAda. But after that, fire up the debugger and try to see where its crashing. Note that in Ada programs often crashes happen during package elaboration before the first line of code in your main even gets called. If you are using Gnat you can step through the elaboration process in GDB as well though. With other compilers, you may have to find some elaboration code to try to put breakpoints into to catch it early enough.